# Emoticons support for textarea or contenteditable div

Tags: angularjs, contenteditable, emoticons

Trying to implement a `textarea` component with emoticons support *while* writing.

I want to be able to backup the original text (ascii chars only) while presenting the filtered/generated html outcome (with an *angular emoticons filter*) on a `div`.

My initial solution is to

```
<textarea ng-model="text" ng-change="..." ng-focus="..."></textarea>
<div ng-bind-html="text | myEmoticonsFilter"></div>
```

but I'm having trouble getting to the part of using a hidden textarea. Also, with this I wouldn't be able to mouse-select text and delete or copy/paste safely.

<del>I also thought of using a `<div contenteditable="true">` but `ng-focus` and `ng-change` wouldn't be handled.</del>

Does anyone have any sugestion on how to continue this?

**Edit 1**: here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nunofaria11/8ajmpuvc/) with an attempt on what I'm doing. Up until now, able to replace the first occurrence, but the behavior remains erratic since that. I'm using a `contenteditable` directive for 2-way data binding and to filter the emoticon pattern.

**Edit 2**: regarding my statement saying that `ng-focus` and `ng-change` wouldn't be handled, that is not true - `ng-focus` works natively on `<div contenteditable="true">` and `ng-change` will work as long as a directive is declared using the `ngModel` and setting the appropriate `$modelValue` and `$viewValue` (an example is provided in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nunofaria11/8ajmpuvc/) in **Edit 1**).

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but you can add change/focus events to contenteditable by using the code provided in [this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example) from the official Angular documentation

Comment: I believe the solution will be meddling directly with `window.getSelection` and `Range` objects when a Node is physically altered in the `contenteditable`

Comment: What about using bower dependency https://github.com/globaldev/angular-emoji-filter It is not actually same mathod you want to use, but on the other hand that is a simple and also powerfull solution. If you need custom icons than you sholud consider doing it different.

Comment: @Miha2255 my problem is not the emoticons filter itself - my problem is making any kind of replacement on a `contenteditable` div. The `scope.$apply(...)` and the html replacement messes with cursor positioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to do this in a consistently cross-browser manner is to use a WYSIWYG field that converts emoji to images.

There's a jQuery plugin [`jquery-emojiarea`](https://github.com/diy/jquery-emojiarea) that does what you need, so you'd just need to create a directive that wraps this plugin and you're off to the races. Since it inputs into a hidden textarea with emoji syntax `:smile:` angular should have no difficulty binding.

Here's a working directive I threw together. http://jsfiddle.net/dboskovic/g8x8xs2t/

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('BaseController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.text = 'This is pretty awesome. :smile: :laughing:';
});
app.directive('emojiInput', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $el, $attr, ngModel) {
            $.emojiarea.path = 'https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dboskovic/jquery-emojiarea-master/packs/basic';
            $.emojiarea.icons = {
                ':smile:': 'smile.png',
                ':angry:': 'angry.png',
                ':flushed:': 'flushed.png',
                ':neckbeard:': 'neckbeard.png',
                 ':laughing:': 'laughing.png'
            };
            var options = $scope.$eval($attr.emojiInput);
            var $wysiwyg = $($el[0]).emojiarea(options);
            $wysiwyg.on('change', function () {
                ngModel.$setViewValue($wysiwyg.val());
                $scope.$apply();
            });
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (data) {
                // emojiarea doesn't have a proper destroy :( so we have to remove and rebuild
                $wysiwyg.siblings('.emoji-wysiwyg-editor, .emoji-button').remove();
                $timeout(function () {
                    $wysiwyg.emojiarea(options);
                }, 0);
                return data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And usage:

```
<textarea ng-model="text" emoji-input="{buttonLabel:'Insert Emoji',wysiwyg:true}"></textarea>
```

> If you want the editable field to convert text like `:(` *as you type* you'll need to fork that jquery plugin and modify it slightly to parse input text on change as well as on init. (like, a couple lines of code)

Comment: Thanks David, I actually went this way using the [`jquery-emojiarea`](https://github.com/diy/jquery-emojiarea) and based a few of my decisions in [angular-emoji-popup](https://github.com/Coraza/angular-emoji-popup) code, which is in its turn uses `jquery-emojiarea`

Comment: However I had to implement my own code because I want custom emojis and menu.  Regarding changes *while* typing, I had to implement event handlers on `keyup` to process the surroundings words for the current caret position with [`Range API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)

Comment: Interesting! @nuno if you want to collaborate on turning that into an angular directive for the rest of the world, I'd be happy to help!